# Trouble nesting elements: Material UI Meteor React

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs, material-ui, meteor-react

When trying to add an `IconButtonMenu` to a list using Material UI in meteor/react, I am getting this error:

> Warning: Failed propType: Invalid prop `rightIconButton` supplied to `ListItem`, expected a single ReactElement. Check the render method of `Request`.

My code is as follows:

```
var {
  List,
  ListItem,
  Divider,
  Styles,
  IconButton,
  IconMenu,
  MenuItem,
  MoreVertIcon
} = MUI;

const { NavigationMoreVert } = MUI.Libs;

Request = React.createClass({
  generateRequests(){
     if(this.props.claims){
        return this.props.claims.map((claim) => {
            return (
                <ListItem
                    primaryText={claim.username + " requested " + claim.portions + " portions"}
                    rightIconButton={
                        <IconMenu iconButtonElement={
                            <IconButton
                                touch={true}
                                tooltip="more"
                                tooltipPosition="bottom-left"
                                >
                                    <NavigationMoreVert color={Styles.Colors.grey400} />
                                </IconButton>
                        } >
                            <MenuItem primaryText="Reply" />
                            <MenuItem primaryText="Forward" />
                        </IconMenu>
                    }
                    style={{color: Styles.Colors.darkBlack}}
                />

            );
        });
    }
  },

  render(){
    return(
      <List subheader="Item Requests">
        <Divider />
        {this.generateRequests()}
      </List>
    );
  }

});
```

It does not seem to like nesting the element. I have trying using const as [the example in the docs does](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/list), but get exactly the same error messages.